# how to find the max value from all the value types in a map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, max

I have a map:

```
typedef map<string, float> my_map;
my_map maxmap;
```

I'm trying to find the maximum float value and its corresponding string key. This is how I'm finding the max float value but I get a segmentation fault and also don't know how to find the corresponding string key.

```
float max = *(max_element(&(maxmap.begin()->second), &(maxmap.end()->second)));
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Break into multiple lines and debug to find precisely where segfault is coming from.

Comment: `maxmap.end()->second` thats an issue

Comment: Downvoting this guy is completely unnecessary.  @djechlin, if you want to help him out, edit his question for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxmap.end()->second` <-- What your trying to do here is dereference the end iterator which is not valid.

**Just use a for loop**:

```
typedef my_map::iterator iter;
iter it = maxmap.begin();
iter end = maxmap.end();

float max_value = it->second;
std::string str = it->first;
for( ; it != end; ++it) {
    if(*it->second > max_value) {
        max_value = it->second;
        str = it->first;
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to also find the string key of the max_value

Comment: okay! got it! I just switched the map placements and put my floats as the key and string as value!

Answer (score 4):

The arguments in the following function call are no iterators:

```
float max = *(max_element(&(maxmap.begin()->second), &(maxmap.end()->second)));
```

Instead, use the function with three arguments, pass the both iterators and a comparison object, that only compares the value, i.e.:

```
struct LessBySecond
{
    template <typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    bool operator()(const Lhs& lhs, const Rhs& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.second < rhs.second;
    }
};

std::max_element(maxmap.begin(), maxmap.end(), LessBySecond());
```

The function returns an iterator that points to the element with the maximum value.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to make use of the bind, either from boost or c++11, and map value_type.  I must say that this is very hard to read.

```
my_map::iterator iter = 
  max_element( maxmap.begin(), maxmap.end(),
               bind(less<float>(),
                    bind(&my_map::value_type::second, placeholders::_1),
                    bind(&my_map::value_type::second, placeholders::_2)) );
```

Answer (score 2):

The arguments to `max_element` must be iterators. `maxmap.begin()` is an iterator, but `&maxmap.begin()->second` is not. You don't know where these floats are stored in memory, and they're certainly not stored contiguously in memory so that you could iterate over them with a `float *`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `max_element` as you should.

In your code, `maxmap.begin()` is a `map<string, float>::iterator`, so `maxmap.begin()->second` is actually a `float`!

The function `max_element` throws because you are giving to it two references to `floats` that are not iterators.

To solve your problem, you should write a `Comparator`, and then use

```
Comparator myComp;
float max = max_element(maxmap.begin(), maxmap.end(), myComp)->second;
```